# Trying to load variable into Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am so confused! I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<span paper-embed="" url="theUrl"></span>
```

and theUrl is a variable that loads a different URL from my ng-controller. Then I have an Angular directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('paperEmbed', function() {
    return {        
        restrict: 'AEC',
        transclude:true,
        scope: {
            key: '=',
            value: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // is does some jQuery here
        }
    };
});
```

my question is, I want to access the URL inside the directive - the variable named *theUrl*, so how do I do that? I looked up on SA and seemed like

```
console.log({{theUrl}});
```

might work but it does not.

Comment: your directive doesn't appear to use either `key` or `value`, but if you want `theUrl` in your directive, you would define it in that same manner.

Comment: Good question! Quick answer: simply use    console.log(attrs.url). long answer is in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Change your scope to

```
scope: {
        key: '=',
        value: '=',
        url: '='
    },
```

And in your link function you can use it like scop.url

Answer (score 0):

You can access it with attrs.url

Answer (score 0):

You can either use attrs.url to access it or you can add the url to the scope:

```
app.directive('paperEmbed', function() {
return {

    restrict: 'AEC',
    transclude:true,
    scope: {
        key: '=',
        value: '=',
        url: '@'
    },

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log(scope.url);

    }
  };
```

Whenever you add a variable to the scope like above, the directive is expecting an html attribute to supply that value. In this case url.

```
<div paper-embed="obj1" key="obj2" value="obj3" url="obj4"></div>
```

`scope.url === obj4;`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to implement a directive with the following:

`<span paper-embed="" url="theUrl"></span>`

you should use `restrict: 'A'`,
the url attribute can be accessed either through your scope declaration as `@` or through the `attrs` object passed into your link function.

as to the `console.log({{theUrl}})`. `{{}}` is specifically design to interpolate javascript-keys in the markup, that is processed through the $compile cycle.

Here is something to get you started:

HTML

```
<span paper-embed url="http://example.com" />
```

javascript

```
var app = angular.module('exampleApp', []);
app.directive('paperEmbed', function() {
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        console.log(attrs.url);
    };
});
```

get a little more detailed information here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object

Answer (score 0):

Among many others, there are two easy ways to do this: 
- First method is to access it using the attrs. 
- Second method is to pass the parameters by defining in the scope.

First method is to use attrs. attrs has all the attributes. You can simply access the url in the link function as attrs.url

```
link:function(scope,element,attrs){
    console.log(attrs.url)
}
```

You will see whatever is placed instead of theUrl is displayed on the console.

The other alternative is to change your directive to the following:
  app.directive('paperEmbed', function() {
return {

```
restrict: 'AEC',
transclude:true,
scope: {
    key: '=',
    value: '=',
    theUrl: '='
},

link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
// is does some jQuery here

}};});
```

Now you can access it in the link function as scope.url. To set the value to be passed simply set $scope.theUrl='whatever your url is' in your ng-controller.